# Webassembly (WAST) and bitclear?

Tags: webassembly

Lets assume I want to convert a lower case to uppercase. Obviously I would need a bitclear to do so:

So something like this:

```
01101100
```

Becomes this:

```
01001100
```

Do we have something like bitclearing so that we can clear a bit inside a byte? An example with wast would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform a bitwise conjunction with a suitable mask, as usual:

```
(i32.and (i32.const 0x6c) (i32.const 0xdf))
```

where `0x6c` is your value, and `0xdf` is the bit mask `11011111`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Coming from javascript im new to assembly but I have been doing a lot of reading lately. Thanks!